# SQLite Unit testing, same tables but different schemas can't create table

Tags: c#, sqlite, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, xunit

I am using EF DbContext to create SQLite Inmemory schema for my unit tests, when it creates tables it throws table already exists even though the are two different schemas like Customer.Order and Client.Order

Mapping files below, i am passing different schema name for each table - it works fine when i run migrations in to SQL server but fails for SQLite when unit testing

```
public class CustomerOrderMap: IEntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    private readonly string _schemaName;

    public CustomerOrderMap(string schema = "")
    {
        _schemaName = schema;
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable($"Order", _schemaName);
    }
}


public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable($"Order", "Client");
}


public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable($"Order", "Customer");
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CustomerOrderMap("Customer"));
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ClientOrderMap("Client"));
}
```

In my Test class

```
_connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
_connection.Open();
_contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
       .UseSqlite(_connection)
       .Options;
using var context = new MyDbContext(_contextOptions);
if (context.Database.EnsureCreated())
{
}
```

Error message - SQLite Error 1: 'table "Order" already exists'.

Any ideas please ?

I tried changing the table names to different like Order1 and Order2 that works fine but I need to create Table names same but different schema in SQLite for my testing

Comment: In SQLite another schema is another db file, so I don't think there's a solution for unit testing. When it comes to tests in which data interaction matters,I'm a big fan of *integration* testing against the same db engine as the production environment.

Comment: @GertArnold same db engine ? do you mean actually use  SQL server for testing ? create a new db for testing purposes by doing  UseSqlServer("connString") ?

Comment: Yes, I should have said same db *provider*.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't support schemas. You need to map them to different table names on SQLite:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ...

    if (Database.IsSqlite())
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer.Order>().ToTable("Customer_Order");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client.Order>().ToTable("Client_Order");
    }
}
```